# Adding submit button object to variable, without referencing ID's

Tags: javascript, forms

I have got an event listener which handles a form submit. Now I want this to be pretty universal and not need to have ID's hard coded. I can reference the form within the `handleSubmit()` function by just adding `this`.

I'm trying to create a variable with my submit button object in it, from `this` form. So then I can change the button's styling if I wish by just referencing this object.

```
//Look for submit button
var f = document.forms[this.id].getElementsByTagName("input"), 
  submitButton;

for (var x=0; x < f.length; x++) {
  if (typeof(f[x]) == "submit") {
    submitButton = f[x];
    break;
  }
}
```

I have got this code above, but it doesn't seem to work as I intended. If I add an alert into the loop `alert(typeof(f[x]))` I just get `Object`, but shouldn't it be for example `Object [HTMLInput]`. I was hoping to get what kind of input it is.

Comment: Far better to add the listener to the form's submit handler than the submit button, which might be a button element or an input element and forms can be submitted without clicking the button. Also, forms can have more than one submit button.

Comment: Everyone keeps saying this, but I can't do that as I upload a file using aJax. onsumbit doesn't wait for the file to finish uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Javascript types with the attribute `type` of `HTMLElement`.

What you want is `f[x].type === "submit"`